# Get Max Count from foreign id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**activity**

id  |  regionId  |  method  |

and **region**

id  |  name  |

activity stores several different method strings, the one I'm most interested in being 'logout'

What I need is to find the region that is logged out the most. I currently have this:

```
SELECT MAX(regionId) FROM activity GROUP BY regionId WHERE method='logout'
```

I'm guessing I need a count in there somewhere, but this query is over my head. Also, I would like it to return region.name instead of activity.regionId

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT regionId, COUNT(method) AS count FROM activity WHERE method = 'logout' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you need the name instead of the region ID, you could do this:

```
SELECT region.name, COUNT(activity.method) AS count FROM region, activity WHERE region.regionId = activity.regionId AND activity.method = 'logout' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This seems to work, how does the limit 1 always get the highest value?

Comment: Oh sorry, it doesn't actually! I just added the important `ORDER BY` part. Now it will order by the logout count, and the `LIMIT 1` will get only the first one.

Comment: Great thanks! This wasn't as complicated as I was making it :)